# How to put in array a different types of field in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2

I'm writing an app for iPhone in objective-c. I want to declare an array that will hold different type of fields , like: int, NSString, bool.
Can I do it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is possible. Just create the array and add the objects you want added.

Answer (score 2):

You can put whatever items in an `NSArray` as long as they are objects. So you have to wrap items that are not objects (such as `BOOL`, `int` and `CGPoint`) in some kind of objects such as [`NSNumber`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000178-DontLinkElementID_9) or [`NSValue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsvalue_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000177-DontLinkElementID_2).

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray] alloc] init];

[array addObject:myString];

[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];

[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0]];

[array addObject:[NSValue valueWithPoint:myPoint]]; // myPoint is a CGPoint

[array addObject:[NSValue valueWithRect:myRect]]; // myRect is a CGRect
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
NSString *string = @"str";
[array addObject:string]; //string
NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
[array addObject:num]; //int
NSNumber *boolNum = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
[array addObject:boolNum]; //bool
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSMutableArray`.

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Now use `addObject:` method to add **objects**. for adding int, bool value create `NSNumber` object.